Is it okay for two pads F.MASK to overlap each other in Kicad
I made a new footprint for XL-0807RGBC-WS2812B based on this datasheet.
When I place this footprint in PCB editor the F.Mask for the pads on this component overlaps each other.
Is this okay?
I assume it is okay because the fabrication facility (JLCPCB) will not put any front solder mask between the pads.


Yes, there's no issue with this. The only possible problem is that it makes it more likely solder will bridge the pads, since there's no soldermask to stop that happening. With appropriate paste application, that shouldn't be a problem.
